Energy Risk.... I guess we can make some room for it?
I was wondering if we could tolerate some posts about energy risk in here

Can you explain little about what you mean?  Are you talking about the risk in energy futures, for instance?

A question about quantitatively gauging risk would be more than welcome! As long as there is an answer (ie, not a discussion) and the rigor of question is appropriate for a site of professionals, then by all means post away.

I don't think the type of finance particularly matters, as long as it's quantitative.
